# Add new keys to a dictionary while incrementing existing values

Tags: python, dictionary, unique-key

I am processing a CSV file and counting the unique values of column 4. So far I have coded this three ways. One uses "if key in dictionary", the second traps the KeyError and the third uses "DefaultDictionary". For example (where x[3] is the value from the file and "a" is a dictionary):

First way:

```
if x[3] in a:
    a[x[3]] += 1
else:
    a[x[3]] = 1
```

Second way:

```
try:
    b[x[3]] += 1
except KeyError:
    b[x[3]] = 1
```

Third way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
c = defaultdict(int)
c[x[3]] += 1
```

My question is: which way is more efficient... cleaner... better... etc. Or is there a better way. Both ways work and give the same answer, but I thought I would tap the hive mind as a learning case.

Thanks -

Comment: Additional edit: I'm running version 2.7. Should have added this earlier!

Comment: `Counter` **is slower** however it has much more functionality than `defaultdict(int)` -- see my answer.

Comment: can you increment multiple values?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`. `Counter` is syntactic sugar for `defaultdict(int)`, but what's cool about it is that it accepts an iterable in the constructor, thus saving an extra step (I assume all of your examples above are wrapped in a for-loop.)

```
from collections import Counter
count = Counter(x[3] for x in my_csv_reader)
```

Prior to the introduction of `collections.Counter`, `collections.defaultdict` was the most idiomatic for this task, so for users < 2.7, use `defaultdict`.

```
from collections import defaultdict
count = defaultdict(int)
for x in my_csv_reader:
    count[x[3]] += 1
```

Comment: I'm going to claim Newbie status on this clarification. Does the "x" in the "for x" portion refer to the individual line returned by the csv.reader? I "think" I implemented the csv reader:

my_csv_reader = csv.reader(open('c:/Test.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
d = Counter(x[3] for x in my_csv_reader)

but d is more than twice as large as the other three methods.

Comment: Yes, `x` refers to the line returned by the csv reader.  What do you mean by d being more than twice as large?  Is it giving the wrong counts?  Please clarify.

Comment: Clarification: My code is incorrect and my question was not complete! There is an if statement surrounding the first three methods that removed duplicate values by matching the current line against the previous line before the value is added to the dictionary. The new method is not in that condition, so I got a total of all lines, not the unique ones!

Comment: @Count Boxer  I see, you'll surely need to code around that.  One way would be to use a `set`.  Something like `my_data = set(my_csv_reader)`, and then `d = Counter(x[3] for x in my_data)`.

Comment: @everybody: Counter is slower. See my answer.

Comment: can you increment multiple values?

Answer (score 6):

You asked which was more efficient. Assuming that you are talking about execution speed: If your data is small, it doesn't matter. If it is large and typical, the "already exists" case will happen much more often than the "not in dict" case. This observation explains some of the results.

Below is some code which can be used with the `timeit` module to explore speed without file-reading overhead. I have taken the liberty of adding a 5th method, which is not uncompetetive and will run on any Python from at least 1.5.2 [tested] onwards.

```
from collections import defaultdict, Counter

def tally0(iterable):
    # DOESN'T WORK -- common base case for timing
    d = {}
    for item in iterable:
        d[item] = 1
    return d

def tally1(iterable):
    d = {}
    for item in iterable:
        if item in d:
            d[item] += 1
        else:
            d[item] = 1
    return d

def tally2(iterable):
    d = {}
    for item in iterable:
        try:
            d[item] += 1
        except KeyError:
            d[item] = 1
    return d

def tally3(iterable):
    d = defaultdict(int)
    for item in iterable:
        d[item] += 1

def tally4(iterable):
    d = Counter()
    for item in iterable:
        d[item] += 1

def tally5(iterable):
    d = {}
    dg = d.get
    for item in iterable:
        d[item] = dg(item, 0) + 1
    return d
```

Typical run (in Windows XP "Command Prompt" window):

```
prompt>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"t=1000*'now is the winter of our discontent made glorious summer by this son of york';import tally_bench as tb" "tb.tally1(t)"
10 loops, best of 3: 29.5 msec per loop
```

Here are the results (msec per loop):

```
0 base case   13.6
1 if k in d   29.5
2 try/except  26.1
3 defaultdict 23.4
4 Counter     79.4
5 d.get(k, 0) 29.2
```

Another timing trial:

```
prompt>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"from collections import defaultdict;d=defaultdict(int)" "d[1]+=1"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.309 usec per loop

prompt>\python27\python -mtimeit -s"from collections import Counter;d=Counter()" "d[1]+=1"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.02 usec per loop
```

The speed of `Counter` is possibly due to it being implemented partly in Python code whereas `defaultdict` is entirely in C (in 2.7, at least).

Note that `Counter()` is NOT just "syntactic sugar" for `defaultdict(int)` -- it implements a full `bag` aka `multiset` object -- see the docs for details; they may save you from reinventing the wheel if you need some fancy post-processing. If all you want to do is count things, use `defaultdict`.

**Update** in response to a question from @Steven Rumbalski: """ I'm curious, what happens if you move the iterable into the Counter constructor: d = Counter(iterable)? (I have python 2.6 and cannot test it.) """

tally6: just does `d = Count(iterable); return d`, takes 60.0 msecs

You could look at the source (collections.py in the SVN repository) ... here's what my `Python27\Lib\collections.py` does when `iterable` is not a Mapping instance:

```
            self_get = self.get
            for elem in iterable:
                self[elem] = self_get(elem, 0) + 1
```

Seen that code anywhere before? There's a whole lot of carry-on just to call code that's runnable in Python 1.5.2 `:-O`

Comment: Nice timings.  I'm curious, what happens if you move the iterable into the Counter constructor: `d = Counter(iterable)`?  (I have python 2.6 and cannot test it.)

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import Counter
Counter(a)
```

Comment: "a" is my dictionary. Is this "Counter(x[3])?

Comment: Isn't "counter" new in 3.1? I'm running 2.7.

Comment: @Count: [it exist in 2.7](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: In Count Boxer's example, `a` is his count dictionary, not his source data.  Implicit in his 3 examples is that they are in a body of a for-loop iterating over his csv file.  All that to say, `a` shouldn't be passed to the constructor, because it's his result, not his source.

Comment: Dang it! Lied to by my IDE! It didn't show up in the drop down list, so I just assumed...

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have access to [Counter](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html), your best bet is your third approach. It's much cleaner and easier to read. In addition, it doesn't have the perpetual testing (and branching) that the first two approaches have, which makes it more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setdefault`.

```
a[x[3]] = a.setdefault(x[3], 0) + 1
```

`setdefault` gets the value of the specified key (`x[3]` in this case), or if it does not exist, the specified value (`0` in this case).

Comment: Please explain why you think that `d[k] = d.setdefault(k, 0) + 1` would be better that `d[k] = d.get(k, 0) + 1`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was thinking of it because it would set the value, but you're doing that anyway.