# Efficient way to count unique elements in array in numpy/scipy in Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a scipy array, e.g.

```
a = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]])
```

I want to count the number of occurrences of each unique element in the array. For example, for the above array a, I want to get out that there is 1 occurrence of [0, 0, 1], 2 occurrences of [1, 1, 1] and 1 occurrence of [1, 0, 1].

One way I thought of doing it is:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)

for elt in a:
  d[elt] += 1
```

is there a better/more efficient way?

thanks.

Comment: Where is the usage of Numpy / Scipy in your example code? Or is this only supposed to get the idea across, wanting to have a Numpy / Scipy function to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If sticking with Python 2.7 (or 3.1) is not an issue and any of these two Python versions is available to you, perhaps the new [collections.Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) might be something for you if you stick to hashable elements like tuples:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter([(0,0,1), (1,1,1), (1,1,1), (1,0,1)])
>>> c
Counter({(1, 1, 1): 2, (0, 0, 1): 1, (1, 0, 1): 1})
```

I haven't done any performance testing on these two approaches, though.

Comment: defaultdict will be faster.  John Machin showed this with timings in an answer earlier today (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4036474/add-new-keys-to-a-dictionary-while-incrementing-existing-values).

Comment: Doesn't use Numpy / Scipy though, as requested by the title of the OP. Also advocates usage of outdated versions of Python. Not sure this is a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can sort the array lexicographically by rows and the look for points where the rows change:

```
In [1]: a = array([[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]])

In [2]: b = a[lexsort(a.T)]

In [3]: b
Out[3]: 
array([[0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])

...


In [5]: (b[1:] - b[:-1]).any(-1)
Out[5]: array([ True,  True, False], dtype=bool)
```

The last array says that the first three rows differ and the third row is repeated twice.

For arrays of ones and zeros you can encode the values:

```
In [6]: bincount(dot(a, array([4,2,1])))
Out[6]: array([0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 2])
```

Dictionaries can also be used. Which of the various methods will be fastest will depend on the sort of arrays you are actually working with.

Answer (score 1):

for python 2.6 <

```
import itertools

data_array = [[0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1]]

dict_ = {}

for list_, count in itertools.groupby(data_array):
    dict_.update({tuple(list_), len(list(count))})
```

Answer (score 0):

The [numpy_indexed](https://github.com/EelcoHoogendoorn/Numpy_arraysetops_EP) package (disclaimer: I am its author) provides a solution similar to the one posted by chuck; which is a nicely vectorized one. But with tests, a nice interface, and many more related useful functions:

```
import numpy_indexed as npi
npi.count(a)
```