# Frequency counts for unique values in a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

How do I efficiently obtain the frequency count for each unique value in a NumPy array?

```
>>> x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
>>> freq_count(x)
[(1, 5), (2, 3), (5, 1), (25, 1)]
```

Answer (score 203, accepted):

Take a look at `np.bincount`:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html

```
import numpy as np
x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
y = np.bincount(x)
ii = np.nonzero(y)[0]
```

And then:

```
zip(ii,y[ii]) 
# [(1, 5), (2, 3), (5, 1), (25, 1)]
```

or:

```
np.vstack((ii,y[ii])).T
# array([[ 1,  5],
         [ 2,  3],
         [ 5,  1],
         [25,  1]])
```

or however you want to combine the counts and the unique values.

Comment: Hi, This wouldn't work if elements of x have a dtype other than int.

Comment: It won't work if they're anything other than non negative ints, and it will be very space inefficient if the ints are spaced out.

Comment: With numpy version 1.10 I found that, for counting integer, it is about 6 times faster than np.unique. Also, note that it does count negative ints too, if right parameters are given.

Comment: @Manoj : My elements x are arrays. I am testing the solution of jme.

Comment: What would be a good analog then for the `return_inverse` option here?

Answer (score 773):

Use [`numpy.unique`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) with `return_counts=True` (for NumPy 1.9+):

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)

>>> print(np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)
 [[ 1  5]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 5  1]
  [25  1]]
```

In comparison with [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html):

```
In [4]: x = np.random.random_integers(0,100,1e6)

In [5]: %timeit unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.5 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit scipy.stats.itemfreq(x)
10 loops, best of 3: 170 ms per loop
```

Comment: If you get the error: TypeError: unique() got an unexpected keyword argument 'return_counts', just do: unique, counts = np.unique(x, True)

Comment: @NumesSanguis What version of numpy are you using? Prior to v1.9, the `return_counts` keyword argument didn't exist, which might explain the exception. In that case, [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.8.0/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html#numpy.unique) suggest that `np.unique(x, True)` is equivalent to `np.unique(x, return_index=True)`, which doesn't return counts.

Comment: My numpy version is 1.6.1 and that may also explain the strange numbers I get as output in the second row, because those are much highter than the actual count.

Comment: In older numpy versions the typical idiom to get the same thing was `unique, idx = np.unique(x, return_inverse=True); counts = np.bincount(idx)`. When this feature was added (see [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/pull/4180)) some informal testing had the use of `return_counts` clocking over 5x faster.

Comment: If you are using **ActivePython**, then numpy is very probably out of date. Check current numpy version with `pip list` AND `pypm list`, then run `pypm uninstall numpy` and `pip install numpy`.

Comment: this is probably the most hidden feature. I have to google it every time after I try `np.count`, `np.value_counts`, `np.freq` etc

Comment: Unfortunately, this is the extremely slow bottleneck for my application, like 100 times as slow as any other command.  Hopefully I can find some faster way.

Answer (score 169):

Use this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1]
>>> np.array(np.unique(x, return_counts=True)).T
    array([[ 1,  5],
           [ 2,  3],
           [ 5,  1],
           [25,  1]])
```

---

Original answer:

Use [`scipy.stats.itemfreq`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.itemfreq.html) (warning: deprecated):

```
>>> from scipy.stats import itemfreq
>>> x = [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1]
>>> itemfreq(x)
/usr/local/bin/python:1: DeprecationWarning: `itemfreq` is deprecated! `itemfreq` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Use instead `np.unique(..., return_counts=True)`
array([[  1.,   5.],
       [  2.,   3.],
       [  5.,   1.],
       [ 25.,   1.]])
```

Comment: Seems like the most pythonic approach by far. Also, I encountered issues with "object too deep for desired array" issues with np.bincount on 100k x 100k matrices.

Comment: I rather suggest the original question poser to change the accpted answer from  the first one to this one, to increase its visiblity

Comment: It's slow for versions before 0.14, though.

Comment: take note that if the array is full of strings, both elements in each of the items returned are strings too.

Comment: Looks like itemfreq has been deprecated

Answer (score 72):

I was also interested in this, so I did a little performance comparison (using [perfplot](https://github.com/nschloe/perfplot), a pet project of mine). Result:

```py
y = np.bincount(a)
ii = np.nonzero(y)[0]
out = np.vstack((ii, y[ii])).T
```

is by far the fastest. (Note the log-scaling.)

[image]

---

Code to generate the plot:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import perfplot
from scipy.stats import itemfreq


def bincount(a):
    y = np.bincount(a)
    ii = np.nonzero(y)[0]
    return np.vstack((ii, y[ii])).T


def unique(a):
    unique, counts = np.unique(a, return_counts=True)
    return np.asarray((unique, counts)).T


def unique_count(a):
    unique, inverse = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    count = np.zeros(len(unique), dtype=int)
    np.add.at(count, inverse, 1)
    return np.vstack((unique, count)).T


def pandas_value_counts(a):
    out = pd.value_counts(pd.Series(a))
    out.sort_index(inplace=True)
    out = np.stack([out.keys().values, out.values]).T
    return out


b = perfplot.bench(
    setup=lambda n: np.random.randint(0, 1000, n),
    kernels=[bincount, unique, itemfreq, unique_count, pandas_value_counts],
    n_range=[2 ** k for k in range(26)],
    xlabel="len(a)",
)
b.save("out.png")
b.show()
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the code to generate the plot. Didn't know about [perfplot](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/perfplot) before now. Looks handy.

Comment: I was able to run your code by adding the option `equality_check=array_sorteq` in `perfplot.show()`. What was causing an error ( in Python 2) was `pd.value_counts` (even with sort=False).

Answer (score 51):

Using pandas module:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
>>> pd.value_counts(x)
1     5
2     3
25    1
5     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: pd.Series() is not necessary. Otherwise, good example. Numpy as well. Pandas can take a simple list as input.

Comment: @YohanObadia - depending on the size f the array, first converting it to a series has made the final operation faster for me. I would guess at the mark of around 50,000 values.

Comment: I edited my answer to take into account the relevant comment from @YohanObadia

Comment: ```df = pd.DataFrame(x)

df = df.astype('category')

print(df.describe()) ``` will give info like ```count   10
unique   4
top      1
freq     5 ```, which can be useful

Answer (score 20):

This is by far the most general and performant solution; surprised it hasn't been posted yet.

```
import numpy as np

def unique_count(a):
    unique, inverse = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True)
    count = np.zeros(len(unique), np.int)
    np.add.at(count, inverse, 1)
    return np.vstack(( unique, count)).T

print unique_count(np.random.randint(-10,10,100))
```

Unlike the currently accepted answer, it works on any datatype that is sortable (not just positive ints), and it has optimal performance; the only significant expense is in the sorting done by np.unique.

Comment: does not work: `AttributeError: 'numpy.ufunc' object has no attribute 'at'`

Comment: A simpler method would be to call `np.bincount(inverse)`

Answer (score 15):

`numpy.bincount` is the probably the best choice. If your array contains anything besides small dense integers it might be useful to wrap it something like this:

```
def count_unique(keys):
    uniq_keys = np.unique(keys)
    bins = uniq_keys.searchsorted(keys)
    return uniq_keys, np.bincount(bins)
```

For example:

```
>>> x = array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1])
>>> count_unique(x)
(array([ 1,  2,  5, 25]), array([5, 3, 1, 1]))
```

Answer (score 8):

Even though it has already been answered, I suggest a different approach that makes use of `numpy.histogram`. Such function given a sequence it returns the frequency of its elements **grouped in bins**.

**Beware though**: it works in this example because numbers are integers. If they where real numbers, then this solution would not apply as nicely.

```
>>> from numpy import histogram
>>> y = histogram (x, bins=x.max()-1)
>>> y
(array([5, 3, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       1]),
 array([  1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,   5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  10.,  11.,
        12.,  13.,  14.,  15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  20.,  21.,  22.,
        23.,  24.,  25.]))
```

Answer (score 5):

Old question, but I'd like to provide my own solution which turn out to be the fastest, use normal **`list`** instead of `np.array` as input (or transfer to list firstly), based on my bench test.

**Check it out** if you encounter it as well.

```
def count(a):
    results = {}
    for x in a:
        if x not in results:
            results[x] = 1
        else:
            results[x] += 1
    return results
```

*For example,*

```
>>>timeit count([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1]) would return:
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 2.26 µs per loop

```
>>>timeit count(np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1]))
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 8.8 µs per loop

```
>>>timeit count(np.array([1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1]).tolist())
```

100000 loops, best of 3: 5.85 µs per loop

While the accepted answer would be slower, and the `scipy.stats.itemfreq` solution is even worse.

---

A more indepth **testing did not confirm** the formulated expectation.

```
from zmq import Stopwatch
aZmqSTOPWATCH = Stopwatch()

aDataSETasARRAY = ( 100 * abs( np.random.randn( 150000 ) ) ).astype( np.int )
aDataSETasLIST  = aDataSETasARRAY.tolist()

import numba
@numba.jit
def numba_bincount( anObject ):
    np.bincount(    anObject )
    return

aZmqSTOPWATCH.start();np.bincount(    aDataSETasARRAY );aZmqSTOPWATCH.stop()
14328L

aZmqSTOPWATCH.start();numba_bincount( aDataSETasARRAY );aZmqSTOPWATCH.stop()
592L

aZmqSTOPWATCH.start();count(          aDataSETasLIST  );aZmqSTOPWATCH.stop()
148609L
```

Ref. comments below on cache and other in-RAM side-effects that influence a small dataset massively repetitive testing results.

Comment: This answer is really good, as it shows `numpy` is not necessarily the way to go.

Comment: @Rain Lee interesting. Have you cross-validated the list-hypothesis also on some non-cache-able dataset size? Lets assume a 150.000 random items in either representation and measured a bit more accurate on a single run as by an example of **aZmqStopwatch.start();count(aRepresentation);aZmqStopwatch.stop()** ?

Comment: Did some testing and yes, there are **huge differences** in real dataset performance. Testing requires a bit more insight into python internal mechanics than running just a brute-force scaled loops and quote non realistic *in-vitro* nanoseconds. As tested - a **np.bincount()** can be made to handle 150.000 array within **less than 600 [us]** while the above **def**-ed **count()** on a pre-converted list representation thereof took more than **122.000 [us]**

Comment: Yeah, my rule-of-thumb is **numpy** for anything that can handle small amounts of latency but has the potential to be very large, **lists** for smaller data sets where latency critical, and of course **real benchmarking** FTW :)

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
x = np.array( [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1] )
print(dict(pd.Series(x).value_counts()))
```

This gives you:
{1: 5, 2: 3, 5: 1, 25: 1}

Comment: `collections.Counter(x)` also give the same result.  I believe the OP wants a output that resembles R `table` function.  Keeping the `Series` may be more useful.

Comment: Please note that it would be necessary to transfer to `pd.Series(x).reshape(-1)` if it is a multidimensional array.

Answer (score 4):

To count **unique non-integers** - similar to Eelco Hoogendoorn's answer but considerably faster (factor of 5 on my machine), I used `weave.inline` to combine `numpy.unique` with a bit of c-code;

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import weave

def count_unique(datain):
  """
  Similar to numpy.unique function for returning unique members of
  data, but also returns their counts
  """
  data = np.sort(datain)
  uniq = np.unique(data)
  nums = np.zeros(uniq.shape, dtype='int')

  code="""
  int i,count,j;
  j=0;
  count=0;
  for(i=1; i<Ndata[0]; i++){
      count++;
      if(data(i) > data(i-1)){
          nums(j) = count;
          count = 0;
          j++;
      }
  }
  // Handle last value
  nums(j) = count+1;
  """
  weave.inline(code,
      ['data', 'nums'],
      extra_compile_args=['-O2'],
      type_converters=weave.converters.blitz)
  return uniq, nums
```

**Profile info**

```
> %timeit count_unique(data)
> 10000 loops, best of 3: 55.1 µs per loop
```

Eelco's pure `numpy` version:

```
> %timeit unique_count(data)
> 1000 loops, best of 3: 284 µs per loop
```

**Note**

There's redundancy here (`unique` performs a sort also), meaning that the code could probably be further optimized by putting the `unique` functionality inside the c-code loop.

Answer (score 3):

multi-dimentional frequency count, i.e. counting arrays.

```
>>> print(color_array    )
  array([[255, 128, 128],
   [255, 128, 128],
   [255, 128, 128],
   ...,
   [255, 128, 128],
   [255, 128, 128],
   [255, 128, 128]], dtype=uint8)


>>> np.unique(color_array,return_counts=True,axis=0)
  (array([[ 60, 151, 161],
    [ 60, 155, 162],
    [ 60, 159, 163],
    [ 61, 143, 162],
    [ 61, 147, 162],
    [ 61, 162, 163],
    [ 62, 166, 164],
    [ 63, 137, 162],
    [ 63, 169, 164],
   array([     1,      2,      2,      1,      4,      1,      1,      2,
         3,      1,      1,      1,      2,      5,      2,      2,
       898,      1,      1,
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

print(pd.Series(name_of_array).value_counts())
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
from collections import Counter
x = array( [1,1,1,2,2,2,5,25,1,1] )
mode = counter.most_common(1)[0][0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Most of simple problems get complicated because simple functionality like order() in R that gives a statistical result in both and descending order is missing in various python libraries. But if we devise our thinking that all such statistical ordering and parameters in python are easily found in pandas, we can can result sooner than looking in 100 different places. Also, development of R and pandas go hand-in-hand because they were created for same purpose. To solve this problem I use following code that gets me by anywhere:

```
unique, counts = np.unique(x, return_counts=True)
d = {'unique':unique, 'counts':count}  # pass the list to a dictionary
df = pd.DataFrame(d) #dictionary object can be easily passed to make a dataframe
df.sort_values(by = 'count', ascending=False, inplace = True)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True) #optional only if you want to use it further
```

Answer (score 0):

some thing like this should do it:

```
#create 100 random numbers
arr = numpy.random.random_integers(0,50,100)

#create a dictionary of the unique values
d = dict([(i,0) for i in numpy.unique(arr)])
for number in arr:
    d[j]+=1   #increment when that value is found
```

Also, this previous post on  [Efficiently counting unique elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037262/efficient-way-to-count-unique-elements-in-array-in-numpy-scipy-in-python)  seems pretty similar to your question, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: The linked question is kinda similar, but it looks like he's working with more complicated data types.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `freq_count` like this:

```
def freq_count(data):
    mp = dict();
    for i in data:
        if i in mp:
            mp[i] = mp[i]+1
        else:
            mp[i] = 1
    return mp
```