# counting the number of samples in a numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, histogram, binning

I have a numpy array of samples, [0, 0, 2.5, -5.0, ...]. In my case all samples are multiples of 2.5. I want tot know how many times each sample occurs. More or less like numpy.hist. In this case something like: [[-5.0, 1], [0, 2], [2.5, 1], ...].

Comment: @:Just check here ..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/numpy-frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-an-array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
[[x,l.count(x)] for x in set(l)]
```

Output

```
[[0, 2], [2.5, 1], [-5.0, 1]]
```

You can also use counter

```
>>> l = [0,0,2.5,-5.0]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({0: 2, 2.5: 1, -5.0: 1})
```