# How to count num of elements vector with numpy python

Tags: python, performance, numpy

For example if i have:

```
a=np.array([[1,1,4,1,4,3,1]])
```

We can see that we have the number 1 four times, the number 4 twice and 3 only ones.

I want to have the following result:

```
array(4,4,2,4,2,1,4)
```

As you can see: each cell is replaced by the count of it's element.

How can i do it in the best efficient way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [numpy: frequency counts for unique values in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/numpy-frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-an-array)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One `vectorized` approach with [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) and [`np.searchsorted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) -

```
# Get unique elements and their counts
unq,counts = np.unique(a,return_counts=True)

# Get the positions of unique elements in a. 
# Use those positions to index into counts array for final output.
out = counts[np.searchsorted(unq,a.ravel())]
```

Sample run -

```
In [86]: a
Out[86]: array([[1, 1, 4, 1, 4, 3, 1]])

In [87]: out
Out[87]: array([4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4])
```

As per the comments from @Jaime, you can use `np.unique` alone like so -

```
_, inv_idx, counts = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)
out = counts[inv_idx]
```

Comment: You can get the same result from `unique` doing `_, inv, cnt = np.unique(a, return_inverse=True, return_counts=True)`, and then `cnt[inv]` will give you what the OP is after.

Comment: @Jaime Added those as edits. Thank you for that input!

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter
ctr = Counter(a.flat)
result = np.array([ctr[i] for i in a.flat])
```

If you want your `result` to have the same dimensions as `a`, use `reshape`:

```
result = result.reshape(a.shape)
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to combine both numpy and Counter:

```
from collections import Counter
a=np.array([[1,1,4,1,4,3,1]])

# First I count the occurence of every element and stor eit in the dict-like counter
# Then I take its get-method and vectorize it for numpy-array usage
vectorized_counter = np.vectorize(Counter(a.flatten()).get)

vectorized_counter(a)
```

Out:

```
array([[4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 1, 4]])
```