# Counting values in list by putting in dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key

```
alist = [5, 7, 6, 2, 9, 1, 7]

D = {}
```

for each unique number in list, set a new key
for each key in dictionary, count number of that key and set to value

this should look like `{5:1, 2:1, 6:1, 9:1, 1:1, 7:2}`

algorithm:

```
For each number n on the input list:
∗ If n in count: set count[n] to count[n] + 1
∗ else: set count[n] to 1
```

I don't know how to go about this. Can anybody show me how?

Attempt:

```
for number in alist:
    if number in D:
        D[number] = D[number]+1
    else:
        D[number] = 1
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#15>", line 3, in
<module> D[number] = D[number]+1 KeyError: 5
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I'm new to this and I'm trying. I tried writing it out but I get an error.

this is what I'm at:

for number in alist:
 if number in alist:
  D[number] = D[number+1]
 else:
  D[number] = 1

Comment: move the `+1` in `D[number+1]` to outside of the brackets like `D[number]+1` or simply change that line to `D[number]+=1`

Comment: You should post the Traceback with your question when you are getting an error as well as the code for your attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you guys, and sorry. Like I said, I'm new to programming and this site. Let me poke at it a bit with the suggestions R Nar made and I'll post the results back.

Comment: You need to check if number is in D not alist

Comment: You should have worte: `if number in D:`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 3, in <module>
    D[number] = D[number]+1
KeyError: 5

Comment: Thank you SirParselot & R Nar. I applied your suggestions to my attempt and it is now working. Thank you!

Comment: updated attempt to solution

Comment: `Numpy.unique` is the fastest way to count. Take a look. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/numpy-most-efficient-frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-an-array  `Collection Counter ` is really slow.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(alist)
Counter({7: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 9: 1})
```

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way to do this is a dictionary comprehension

```
count_dict = {elem:a_list.count(elem) for elem in a_list}
```

It's like a for loop but it specifies both the key and value for each dictionary item.

Answer (score 1):

[Ayush Shanker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33901956/1473772) is a perfectly valid way to do what you want. I'll point out how to fix the code you have now.

First, in these two lines

```
for number in alist:
    if number in alist:
```

You're basically saying "for every number in alist, check to see if it's in alist". Of course it is! So, you really want `if number in D:` for the second line, because then you're checking to see if the number is in the dictionary you're building.

The second problem is this:

```
        D[number] = D[number+1]
```

`number` and `number+1` here are indices, so you're referring to two different elements in `D`. The solution is to move the `+1` outside. This is what the fixed code looks like:

```
for number in alist:
    if number in D:
        D[number] = D[number] + 1
    else:
        D[number] = 1
```

To be more Pythonic, you can also replace `D[number] = D[number] + 1` with `D[number] += 1`.

Answer (score 0):

To fix you code and algorithm, you need to check if `n` is in `D.keys()` (which returns list of keys of `D` dictionary:

```
>>> D = {}
>>> for n in alist:
    if n in D.keys():
        D[n] += 1
    else:
        D[n] = 1


>>> D
{1: 1, 2: 1, 5: 1, 6: 1, 7: 2, 9: 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

```
 def mode(somelist):
        count = {}
        for n in alist:
            if n in count:
                count[n]+=1
            else:
                count[n] = 1
        return(count)
```