# Efficient GROUP BY query on numpy recarray

Tags: python, numpy, querying, recarray

I have a dataset of product purchases logs with 6 columns:
**purchase_date, user_address, user_id, product_id, brand_id, retailer_id**. 
All contain integers, except user_address which is a string.

I need to get the top 5 brands selling the most items over the whole dataset, i.e. the ones having the most entries in the data.

In SQL, I believe it would look like the following (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
SELECT brand_id, COUNT(*)
FROM data
GROUP BY brand_id
```

I've tried doing that in python with a numpy recarray as follows:

```
items_sold_per_brand = np.empty(len(data), dtype=[('brand_id', 'int'), ('count', 'int')])

brands = np.unique(data['brand_id'])    # array of unique brands
for i, brand in enumerate(np.nditer(brands)):     # For any unique brand
    items_sold_per_brand[i] = (brand, len(data[data['brand_id'] == brand]))    # get the number of rows with the current brand

top5 = np.sort(items_sold_per_brand, order='count')[-5:]    # sort the array over the count values
print(top5[::-1])    # print the last five entries
```

It works, except it is taking around 15 seconds to run on a ~100000 rows dataset, with roughly 12000 different brands, which seems too long. The for loop is what takes the longest.

Is there a more elegant and efficient way to do this, by maybe using numpy's recarray querying methods?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you try the `unique` `return_counts` parameter?

Comment: Looks like I was overthinking the whole problem, "return_counts" worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While the nominated duplicate [numpy: most efficient frequency counts for unique values in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/numpy-most-efficient-frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-an-array) is relevant, I think it ignores some important issues in this code.  The accepted answer, `bincount` probably isn't useful.  And you many need some help in applying the newer `unique` `return_counts` answer.

A test script:

```
import numpy as np
# simple data array
data=np.zeros((20,),dtype=[('brand_id',int),('id',int)])
data['brand_id']=np.random.randint(0,10,20)
data['id']=np.arange(20)

items_sold_per_brand = np.empty(len(data), dtype=[('brand_id', 'int'), ('count', 'int')])
brands = np.unique(data['brand_id']) 
print('brands',brands)
for i, brand in enumerate(np.nditer(brands)):
    items_sold_per_brand[i] = (brand, len(data[data['brand_id'] == brand]))
top5 = np.sort(items_sold_per_brand, order='count')[-5:]    
print('top5',top5[::-1]) 

# a bit of simplification
brandids = data['brand_id']
brands = np.unique(brandids)
# only need space for the unique ids 
items_sold_per_brand = np.zeros(len(brands), dtype=[('brand_id', 'int'), ('count', 'int')])
items_sold_per_brand['brand_id'] = brands
for i, brand in enumerate(brands):  # dont need nditer
    items_sold_per_brand['count'][i] = (brandids == brand).sum()
top5 = np.sort(items_sold_per_brand, order='count')[-5:]    
print('top5',top5[::-1])    

brands,counts = np.unique(data['brand_id'],return_counts=True)
print('counts',counts)

items_sold_per_brand = np.empty(len(brands), dtype=[('brand_id', 'int'), ('count', 'int')])
items_sold_per_brand['brand_id']=brands
items_sold_per_brand['count']=counts
tops = np.sort(items_sold_per_brand, order='count')[::-1]
print('tops',tops)

ii = np.bincount(data['brand_id'])
print('bin',ii)
```

produces

```
1030:~/mypy$ python3 stack38091849.py 
brands [0 2 3 4 5 6 7 9]
top5 [(99072, 1694566490) (681217, 1510016618) (1694566234, 1180958979)
 (147063168, 147007976) (-1225886932, 139383040)]
top5 [(7, 4) (2, 4) (0, 3) (9, 2) (6, 2)]
counts [3 4 2 1 2 2 4 2]
tops [(7, 4) (2, 4) (0, 3) (9, 2) (6, 2) (5, 2) (3, 2) (4, 1)]
bin [3 0 4 2 1 2 2 4 0 2]
```

Initializing `items_sold_per_brand` with empty and the size of `data` potentially leaves random counts that don't get over written during the iteration.  `zeros` with the smaller `brands` size takes care of that.

`nditer` isn't needed for a simple iteration like this.

`bincount` is fast, but creates bins for all potential values in the `data` range.  So potentially there are 0 size bins.