# amplitude spectrum in Python

Tags: python

I have a given array with a length of over `1'000'000` and values between `0` and `255` (included) as integers. Now I would like to plot on the x-axis the integers from `0` to `255` and on the y-axis the quantity of the corresponding x value in the given array (called `Arr` in my current code).

I thought about this code:

```
    list = []
    for i in range(0, 256):
        icounter = 0
        for x in range(len(Arr)):
            if Arr[x] == i:
                icounter += 1
        list.append(icounter)
```

But is there any way I can do this a little bit faster (it takes me several minutes at the moment)? I thought about an `import ...`, but wasn't able to find a good package for this.

Comment: You're essentially just trying to make a histogram, so [`numpy.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) or [`scipy.stats.histogram`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.histogram.html) will be very efficient and accomplish this task

Comment: @CoryKramer Thx it works.

Comment: This question was already answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/numpy-most-efficient-frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-an-array

Comment: @Anil_M oh I havn't been finding this one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `numpy.bincount` for this task (look for more details [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html))

```
import numpy as np
list = np.bincount(Arr)
```

Answer (score 0):

While I completely agree with the previous answers that you should use a standard histogram algorithm, it's quite easy to greatly speed up your own implementation. Its problem is that you pass through the entire input *for each bin*, over and over again. It would be much faster to only process the input once, and then write only to the relevant bin:

```
def hist(arr):
    nbins = 256
    result = [0] * nbins   # or np.zeroes(nbins)
    for y in arr:
        if y>=0 and y<nbins:
            result[y] += 1
    return result
```