# Find frequency of elements in a dask array without losing information about the array shape?

Tags: dask

I need to find the frequency of every elements in the array while keeping the information about the array shape. This is because I'll need to iterate over it later on.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10741692/11337357) solution as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25943480/11337357) one. It works well for numpy however it doesn't seem to work in dask due to the limitation of dask arrays needing to know their size for most operation.

```py
import dask.array as da

arr = da.from_array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])

unique, counts = da.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

print(unique)
# dask.array<getitem, shape=(nan,), dtype=int64, chunksize=(nan,)>

print(counts)
# dask.array<getitem, shape=(nan,), dtype=int64, chunksize=(nan,)>
```

I am looking for something similar to this:

```py
import dask.array as da

arr = da.from_array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])

print(da.frequency(arr))
# {1: 3, 2: 1, 3:1, 4:2}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that this solution was the fastest for a large amount (~37.5 Billion elements) of data with many unique values (>50k).

```py
import dask
import dask.array as da

arr = da.from_array(some_large_array)

bincount = da.bincount(arr)
bincount = bincount[bincount != 0]  # Remove elements not in the initial array
unique = da.unique(arr)

# Allows to have the shape of the arrays
unique, counts = dask.compute(unique, bincount)
unique = da.from_array(unique)
counts = da.from_array(counts)

frequency = da.transpose(
    da.vstack([unique, counts])
)
```

Comment: Nice work!  You could probably switch from dask.array functions to numpy functions after your call to dask.compute.  You probably don't need Dask at this point any longer.  http://docs.dask.org/en/latest/best-practices.html#stop-using-dask-when-no-longer-needed

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can call `dask.compute` directly after creating the frequency counts.  Presumably at this point your dataset is small and now would be a good time to transition away from Dask Array and back to NumPy

```
import dask
import dask.array as da

arr = da.from_array([1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4])

unique, counts = da.unique(arr, return_counts=True)

unique, counts = dask.compute(unique, counts)
result = dict(zip(unique, counts))
# {1: 3, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 2}
```

Comment: This works when I try on a sample of my dataset (~600MB) however I not sure how well it would scale on the full dataset (~75GB). I will definitely give it a shot. Thank you!!

Comment: I tried the solution you suggested however it seems to slow down considerably with large amount of data and many unique values. I managed to find another solution which is quite fast (see below). I think this might be due to the `return_counts=True` in `da.unique`. Maybe it would require some optimisation; I can open an issue on github I you think it can be useful.