# How to count dataframe from both columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe and want to count how many times the name appears in both columns

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'TEAM 1':['Mark','Peter','Andy','Tony'],'Team 2':
                  ['Andy','Tony','Jhon','Peter']})
```

so the name Andy would count as 2, while Jhon is 1 
Expected Output

```
Mark 1
Andy 2
Tony 2
Jhon 1
Peter 2
```

I used this code but it does not work

```
data.groupby('TEAM 1')['Team 2'].count()
```

Answer (score 8):

Use [`stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
>>> data.stack().value_counts()
Andy     2
Tony     2
Peter    2
Jhon     1
Mark     1
```

As pointed out in [`Ch3steR's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213314/how-to-count-dataframe-from-both-columns/63213350?noredirect=1#comment111781187_63213350), converting the df to `numpy.array` then flattening it using [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) before calling `pd.value_counts` yields around 2X faster results:

```
>>> pd.value_counts(data.to_numpy().ravel())
Andy     2
Tony     2
Peter    2
Jhon     1
Mark     1
dtype: int64
```

Benchmarking:

```
>>> data = pd.concat([data] * 1000000)   # 4_000_000 rows

>>> %timeit data.stack().value_counts()
1.21 s ± 27.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

>>> %timeit pd.value_counts(data.to_numpy().ravel())
667 ms ± 16.4 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**UPDATE:** As per [`anky's comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63213314/how-to-count-dataframe-from-both-columns/63213350?noredirect=1#comment111790769_63213350) [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) proves to be even faster:

```
>>> %timeit pd.Series(Counter(np.ravel(data)))
501 ms ± 4.28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Nice answer, alternative using *NumPy* `n,c = np.unique(df.to_numpy(), return_counts=True); pd.Series(c, index=n)` don't if this is efficient or not.

Comment: From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096495/12416453) `np.unique` over large array is slower than `pd.value_counts`.

Comment: `pd.value_counts(df.to_numpy().ravel())` was 2x faster than using `df.stack().value_counts()` over df of shape (400K,2)

Comment: `np.unique` is much slower for larger dataframes, I will add the `ravel` one to the answer if you don't mind. Or if you want to add that as an answer, that's fine as well.

Comment: Sure, commented for that ;) `np.unique` is slower for large dataframes [here's bencmarking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43096495/12416453)

Comment: `%timeit Counter(np.ravel(data))` proves even faster for me  after you have imported the same `from collections import Counter`