# Looking for efficient process to count number of times a member appears in data

Tags: python, performance

I have a rather large - hundreds of thousands of entries - lenght of data in a vector, which contains numbers from 1 to 10 000. I want to count the number of times each number is mentioned, then store this number into another vector. So I want a vector where the index corresponds to the number and the value to the amount of times it appears in the original data.

I do this by defining the vector element as a function, then call this function in a for-loop like this

```
def detector_count(x):
    detector_count = 0
    for i in range(0, len(df2)):  #df2 is the lengthy data vector
      if df2[i] == x:
         detector_count += 1
    return detector_count

# In this vector the number of times each number 1,...,10K is mentioned is stored

photons = np.zeros(10000)
for i in range(0, 10000):
  photons[i] = detector_count(i)
```

This works, but I suspect is horribly inefficient. When the number is 10 000, this already takes a while. Eventually as the number of detectors - 10 000 detectors atm - is raised by a few orders its going to take hours. How can this process be done more efficiently?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-a-numpy-array

Comment: You're approach is O(n^2) - very inefficient. Read the answers in the linked question above or try [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)

Comment: Note that `photons` is an array of double-precision floating-point values. Storing integer inside is not efficient. Please consider specifying the parameter `dtype` for `np.zeros`. For example: `np.zeros(10_000, dtype=np.int32)`. 32-bit integers are enough to store values from about -2_000_000_000 to 2_000_000_000 which seems clearly enough for your use-case. They take twice less space and can be computed faster than double-precision. It might even be safe to use 16-bit ones here.

Answer (score 1):

```
df2_array = np.array(df2)
photons = np.bincount(df2_array, minlength=10001)[1:]
```

Above code is for counting number of times each number 1,...,10K is mentioned is stored
Since my fellow user @slothrop made a good point about you may wanting something a little different, if you want to include 0 you should remove the latter part and instead just use:

```
df2_array = np.array(df2)
photons = np.bincount(df2_array, minlength=10001)
```

In photons array the index coresponds to the number and the value coresponds to the amount of occurrences
Example for demonstration:
[image]

Comment: Looks good but OP says *"So I want a vector where the index corresponds to the number."* So `photons[1]` should be the number of occurrences of 1, i.e. the `[1:]` is not needed.

Comment: @slothrop but he says : "which contains numbers from 1 to 10 000." . What do you think after my comment, I can edit it if necassary what do you think?

Comment: That's true, but IMO another thing points in favour of excluding the `[1:]`. OP's original code has `for i in range(0, 10000)` suggesting that `photons[0]` should be the count of zeroes (even if that count is always zero).

Comment: @slothrop You make a good case, I edited and mentioned your point incase that was what the OP is trying to do.