# Fastest way to count the number of occurrences of a list of items from a numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a histogram of an image, basically a histogram of an image is a graph that show how many times a pixel that is converted to a 0-255 value occurs in an image. With Y axis number of occurance and X axis the pixel value.

[image]

And what i need is the total number of pixel value from 75-125

```
image= cv2.imread('grade_0.jpg')
listOfNumbers = image.ravel() #generates the long list of 0-255 values from the image) type numpy.ndarray
```

Right now my code does this by converting the numpy.ndarray to a list and counting each values one by one

```
start = time.time()
numberlist = list(list0fNumbers)

sum = 0
for x in range(75,125):
    sum = sum + numberlist.count(x)
end = time.time()

print('Sum: ' + str(sum))
print('Execution time_ms: ' + str((end-start) * 10**3))
```

Result :

```
Sum: 57111
Execution time_ms: 13492.571830749512
```

I would be doing something like this for thousands of images and with just this image alone it took 13 seconds. It is just too ineffecient. Any recommendation on how to speed it up to about less than 10ms? I wont be just getting the sum of 75-125, but other ranges as well, e.g. 0-80,75-125,120-220,210-255. Assuming those take 13seconds too to process a single 256x256 pixel image takes about 60 seconds which i would say is a bit long even for a slow computer.

Here is a sample image:

[image]

Comment: Please provide a reproducible image

Comment: Related: [Frequency counts for unique values in a NumPy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10741346/frequency-counts-for-unique-values-in-a-numpy-array)

Comment: @mozway , i have added a sample images as suggested :)

Comment: It's not clear what you are starting with. You say "I have a histogram" but then you show code where it looks like you are creating a histogram. Have you looked at: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html

Comment: @Mark the histogram graph was made by matplotlib, the graph itself is not important since that graph was made from the numpy.ndarray. it would be more inefficient if i work on the graph itself when i have access to the source data where it was made from. numpy.histogram returns an array so i still have to do the counting which is where my bottle neck is

Comment: Andre's answer using `bincount` is a better idea, but just to be clear, your bottleneck isn't from counting, it's from looping through the entire image as a python list 50 times. `numpy.histgram` does this once without the overhead from the list then you can just slice the elements you want and sum. In other words: `np.histogram(img, range=[0, 256], bins=256)` then slice like the answer below.

Comment: @DrakeJest thanks, you can use a simple boolean comparison, see below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use simple boolean operators:

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('grade_0.jpg')

out = ((image>=75)&(image<125)).sum()

# 57032
```

Or, as suggested by @jared:

```
out = np.count_nonzero((image>=75)&(image<125))
```

Timing of the count:

```
# sum
170 µs ± 2.81 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)

# count_non_zero
47.6 µs ± 2.94 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

---

Edit: I realize you want to process several bins, this could be done using:

```
bins = [(0,80),(75,125),(120,220),(210,255)]
out = {f'{a}-{b}': np.count_nonzero((image>=a)&(image<b)) for a, b in bins}
# {'0-80': 26274, '75-125': 57032, '120-220': 86283, '210-255': 40967}
```

But this will read again the image's data for each bin.

In this case, `bincount`, as suggested by @Andrej, could indeed preferred since it only counts the pixels once:

```
bins = [(0,80),(75,125),(120,220),(210,255)]

counts = np.bincount(image.ravel())
out = {'-'.join(map(str, t)): counts[slice(*t)].sum() for t in bins}
# {'0-80': 26274, '75-125': 57032, '120-220': 86283, '210-255': 40967}
```

The timings will depends on the size of the image and the number of bins. For small images, counting again might be more efficient, while for large ones `bincount` could be better (but, surprisingly, not always).

256 x 256

```
# count_nonzero in loop
198 µs ± 8.75 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# bincount
440 µs ± 6.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

512 x 512:

```
# count_nonzero in loop
918 µs ± 31 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

# bincount
1.76 ms ± 26.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

1024 x 1024:

```
# count_nonzero in loop
11 ms ± 210 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# bincount
8.15 ms ± 437 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

2048 x 2048:

```
# count_nonzero in loop
47.1 ms ± 3.01 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# bincount
48.8 ms ± 3.02 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: I usually find that `np.count_nonzero` is faster than summing, though I'm not entirely sure why since internally it calls `.sum()`. Not sure if that's worth me writing in another answer or adding to yours.

Comment: @jared that's true, I forgot about this one. Surprisingly, most of the time it's even faster to repeat the count_nonzero than summing the bincount.

Comment: Its interesting to see that `np.count_nonzero` fall off the larger the image, and it looks like for my application 256x256 pixel  `np.count_nonzero` is the way to go. I noticed also you did not use .ravel() any particular reason why?

Comment: @DrakeJest because it's not needed. We can keep the original shape for this operation. I didn't time the operation with an extra `ravel` (you *could* use it), but I wouldn't expect it to be more efficient. Give it a try, we never know ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`np.bincount`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html#numpy-bincount):

```py
y = np.bincount(arr)
print(y[75:125].sum())
```

Prints:

```
57032
```

---

Full code:

```py
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image

# Open your image file:
image_path = "image.png"
image = Image.open(image_path)

arr = np.array(image).ravel()

y = np.bincount(arr)
print(y[75:125].sum())
```

Comment: i really like this one its so simple just 2 lines of code, and on my computer it clocked at 1ms